# Can't find appropriate image on Docker Hub while it appears to run OK on Bitbucket

Tags: python, docker, bitbucket

I am working on a project and using Bitbucket as my remote server. I have set up a basic pipeline with the following:

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Python.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/x4UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: python:3.8.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - pip
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pytest -v test_cliff_erosion_equations.py
```

Since there are slight differences in results between the pipeline and my local machine, I would like to debug this pipeline locally using Docker as explained in the [bitbucket docs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/debug-pipelines-locally-with-docker/). In fact, I would like to develop my entire program within the same containerized environment, both locally and remotely. I have realized that PyCharm community version won't allow you to do this, so I've decided to switch to VSCode which appears to have full Docker support.

As you can see the image is `python:3.8.3` I had a look through [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) but I can't find it! However it seems to run just fine in Bitbucket. Why is this so?

Comment: When I filter by tag on Docker Hub I can find `3.8.3` back just fine. https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&name=3.8.3

Comment: The image is present on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.8.3/images/sha256-b8c37d821abb6d1bb4110bbad9368ae2da3b100a57ef14ed25ce5c1f6b79a2c9?context=explore